# I want to show all tables that have specified column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I get a list of all the tables that have a specific column name?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Pretty simple on a per database level

```
Use DatabaseName
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Where column_name = 'ColName'
```

Comment: This solution includes views.  Is there a way to determine which ones are tables and which are views?

Comment: See this to to get only tables or tables and views [MSSQL] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Comment: Works for MySQL too :) !

Comment: @DanKaufman join as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30674301/125981 (I know this is old but making it easier for others)

Answer (score 18):

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumn'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the information schema views:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ID'
```

Here's the MSDN reference for the "Columns" view:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to query an Oracle database, you might want to use

```
select owner, table_name 
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'ColName';
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name,*
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE c.name LIKE '%YOUR_COLUMN%' 
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

[In depth article by SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT      T.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColName'
```

This returns tables only and ignores views for anyone who is interested!

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you're looking for in the information schema: 
[SQL Server 2005 System Tables and Views](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3508881/SQL-Server-2005-System-Tables-and-Views.htm)
  I think you need SQL Server 2005 or higher to use the approach described in this article, but a similar method can be used for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

--get tables that contains selected columnName

```
SELECT  c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%batchno%'
```

its worked...