# Finding the column in tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008: find all tables containing column with specified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/sql-server-2008-find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

Hi all,

I have 30 tables in my database, in some of tables i have a common column, assume 'eno'. How can i find the tables of 'eno'. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS system view`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_name = 'eno'
```