# Searching for all tables in a Database that contain a field

Tags: sql

Working in Business Objects 6.5, I would like to search all the  tables in the environment to find the ones that contain the feild "POID"

Comment: You want all the tables in the database that contain a specific field name?  Which DBMS?

Comment: I'm in an old version of Business Objects.  i know that I can use 'select * from [table_name] to find all fields in a table, but now I want to find all tables in the universe that have a feild "POID"

Comment: Is [This][1] you were looking for?

Regards,
Praveen

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/sql-server-2008-find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the repository tables, you can use this query to search for all tables in all universes that contain the specified field name:

```
select
    u.uni_longname,
    t.tab_name,
    c.column_name,
from
    unv_table t,
    unv_columns c,
    unv_universe u
where
    t.table_id = c.table_id
    and t.universe_id = c.universe_id
    and u.universe_id = t.universe_id
    and t.column_name = 'xxxxxx'
```

If you don't have access to the repository tables, I would just export the universe to PDF (File->Export in Designer), then just search the PDF for the field.