# find sql table name with a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is their any other way or `sql` query to find the database table names with a particular column than shown below,

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'NameID'
```

Comment: Why would you need another way?

Comment: That's the way if you want to use standards SQL. If you don't, then you need to add a tag for your specific RDBMS product (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Comment: this might differ depending on the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: watch out querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA should be very heavy for your server.

Comment: that's why i was asking for another approach..

Comment: @RohanS - then you need to tell us what database product you're using. Any other approach will not be using standard SQL - it will be using product-specific features.

Comment: Since your previous SQL questions have been about SQL Server, I've added that tag. If that's incorrect, please re-tag with a different product.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all tables containing column with specified name - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can query [`sys.columns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx).

Something like:

```
 SELECT
     t.name
 FROM
     sys.columns c
        inner join
     sys.tables t
        on
           c.object_id = t.object_id
 WHERE
     c.name = 'NameID'
```

You might want an additional lookup to resolve the schema name, if you have tables in multiple schemas.

Answer (score 7):

you can run this query

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Column%' -- write the column you search here
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Database. Use the below query:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'NameID';
```

If you’ve got DBA privileges, you can try this command instead:

```
select table_name from dba_tab_columns where column_name = 'NameID';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 
ORDINAL_POSITION as org_pos, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as CML
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%Here Column Name%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```