# Fetch Column Name from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Requirements:

1. I want to write a SQL Command to fetch the Column Names from a Participant Table where the Column Name must be matching the word `%Track%`.
2. I want to fetch all the Table Name in the Database where it contains Column Name LIKE `%Track%`

`"USER_TAB_COLUMNS"` Does not run but gives error. `Invalid object name 'USER_TAB_COLUMNS'.`

```
SELECT [name] AS [Column Name]
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'V' AND [Name] = 'Participant')
```

Runs but there is no record fetched by this query.

Please suggest me the Query which will give me the desired resultant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql select with column name like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/sql-select-with-column-name-like)

Comment: @Tanner I have 2 questions here. This will be serving only one of the requirement. Please unmark it as duplicate if possible

Comment: ok, well this answers the other part of your question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211645/find-sql-table-name-with-a-particular-column, you should try searching before  posting, these types of  question are quite common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to fetch all the Table Name in the Database where it contains Column Name LIKE %Track%

You can try this

```
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE  '%Track%'
```

---

> 1. I want to write a SQL Command to fetch the Column Names from a Participant Table where the Column Name must be matching the word %Track%

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Participant' and column_name like '%Track%'
```

And if you want to find in all the tables the

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name like '%Track%'
```

Comment: Both of them actually served my purpose. But could you please help me to improve the query like. the First Query is fetching all the table name more than once. I want the table name to be coming only once.

Comment: I am trying to apply `group by` but it is not giving the correct result.

Comment: None of the issues raised in the article apply here, so it is not a criticism by any means, more of a side note, but Aaron Bertrand has written a pretty compelling case [against the use of the information schema](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT  *
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE   
                    COLUMN_NAME = 'Your column name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sys.columns 
where name like '%your wild card%' 
and object_id = object_id('tablename')
```

Comment: this serve my 1st Requirement. Please also let me know about the second one

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. It might help you. The query would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Participant'
```