# Need to find specific column name from database

Tags: sql, database

I have one database on my server I want to filter one column name from the whole database where that column is used.

E.g: If column name is **"AlternativeID"** is exist in 5 tables and than I want the query that find this column name exists in which tables.?

I find the following query to find specific column name from database.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name LIKE '%AlternativeID%'
```

I hope this is make sense to everyone. Any help will appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them

Comment: @Incognito That link I already try but its not meet my requirement what I want is something else from that all queries.

Comment: `sys.columns` is sql server specific. your question is tagged with mysql. which one are you using?

Comment: @ughai I updated. I need for sql ...

Comment: Do you mean you want a vendor agnostic query which works across sql server, mysql, oracle etc... In that case use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: possible duplicate of [find all tables containing column with specified name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%AlternativeID%'
```

OR...

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%AlternativeID%'
```

Source : [Find all tables containing column with specified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('AlternativeID')
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabaseName';
```