# Finding column name and using it in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I would like to write a query where first I look for a column name in specific table using `LIKE "%MyName"` phrase and then use this column name in select statement to find a value in that column in the table Prąd.

I've tried to do so, using tips from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name) topic.
The code I wrote so far looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    (
    SELECT c.name AS ColName
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE 'energia%'
    )   
FROM Prąd
WHERE ID = 
    (
    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM 
    Prąd
    )
```

What I get as a result is just the column name, not a value in specified column and row in the table Prąd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a dynamic statement.

```
Declare @sqlCommand varchar(max) 
declare @columnName varchar(250)

Set @columnName = ( SELECT c.name  FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id WHERE c.name LIKE 'energia%' )

Set @sqlCommand = ' select ''' +@columnName + ''' FROM Prąd WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Prąd ) '

Exec @sqlCommand
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost worked perfectly - I got a "name is not a valid identifier" error and it seems that: 
"If you do not have the brackets, SQL Server assumes the value of the variable to be a stored procedure name"
so it should be Exec (@sqlCommand)

Comment: Yes. Sry i was writing from my phone. I edited. Mark it as a correct answer then. I 'm glad it helped

Comment: I wish I could - I don't have enough reputation, but I am still grateful.

Comment: @kkris77 You don't need a high reputation to close your question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compose a dynamic SQL statement concatenating the found column name into a string variable, then `execute` that. Quick searching will show you a couple of available ways to do this. If deploying an application for others to use, ensure you choose a method that is protected against injection.

Also note that if your column name `select` can possibly return more than one result - which a `like` filter very much can - you need to account for this in your dynamic SQL composition.