# Searching and listing a column name in all databases of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I search for a given column name (e.g. like `'%tag%'`) in all databases of a server?

Looking for some result like:

```
Database         TableName         ColumnName
-----------------------------------------------
```

I Needed from all databases in one shot, not just a single database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all tables containing column with specified name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @query nvarchar(max), @crlf nvarchar(2), @columnName nvarchar(50)
    set @query=''
    set @crlf=char(13)

    /*Set the name you are searchng*/
    set @columnName='%tag%'


    SELECT @query=@query + 'select '''+name+''' as ''Datadase'', t.name as ''Table'', c.name as ''Column'' 
from ['+name+'].sys.tables t 
inner join ['++name+'].sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id     
where c.name like '''+ @columnName +''' union all'+ @crlf +char(13) 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

    set @query=left(@query,len(@query)-len(' union all'+ @crlf))
    exec (@query)
```

Comment: tried SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id 
WHERE c.name like'%tag%' but returned nothing. Do I select master? I guess I do need it dynamic.

Comment: Here you go, a full answer.

Comment: thanks. I get the following error:Msg 451, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT statement column 2.
Msg 451, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT statement column 3.