# Auto rename columns when self joining

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a shortcut to auto rename columns (like with a prefix or suffix) when self joining?  I am comparing a lot of columns and it is a hassle to list them out and alias them.

A simplified example is:

```
WITH C as
(
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.KEY=B.KEY WHERE ....
)
SELECT * from C
```

It balks obviously because every column has a dupe.

Comment: No there isn't unless you start using dynamic sql and the system objects to build your sql. You shouldn't be using * in the column list anyway. You should only select the columns you actually need.

Comment: I'm comparing every column and need them all.  I didn't think there was a shortcut. Thanks

Comment: Then you will have to manually type them in or use dynamic sql to do it.

Comment: You could always get the column list from system tables and concatenate a comma and prefix to save some typing.  Such as from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name for system tables...  Work Smarter, not harder!

Answer (score 0):

Had a few minutes so I threw together this quick example of how you could utilize t-sql to help you build your t-sql. You could use this and then copy and paste into the body of your cte.

```
create table SelfJoinExample
(
    Col1 int
    , Col2 int
)

select x.y + '.' + name + ' as ' + name + x.y + ', '
from sys.columns
cross join (values('a'),('b'))x(y)
where object_id = object_id('SelfJoinExample')
```