# Find all tables that have ROWGUIDCOL

Tags: sql, sql-server

IS there a system table I can join to so I can query to find all tables with a column flagged as ROWGUIDCOL?

thanks!

Comment: Hope this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize [`sys.columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) with [`COLUMNPROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS tab_name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id, name, 'IsRowGuidCol') = 1
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/736f9/3/0)**</kbd>

---

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID());
CREATE TABLE MyTable2(ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL PRIMARY KEY 
                      DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID());
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╗
║ tab_name ║
╠══════════╣
║ MyTable2 ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: Why use `COLUMNPROPERTY`? wouldn't it be simpler to do `FROM sys.columns where is_rowguidcol = 1`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this sql query to achive your goal. `Objects.Type = 'U'` is user table.

```
SELECT O.name AS table_name,
       C.name AS column_name
FROM sys.objects AS O
    JOIN sys.columns AS C ON C.object_id = O.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'U'
        AND C.is_rowguidcol = 1
```

Comment: Just because it's a uniqueidentifier, it may not be a rowguidcol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COLUMNPROPERTY()` like so:

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(C.TABLE_NAME), c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsRowGuidCol') 
AS IsRowGuidCol , *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(C.TABLE_NAME), c.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsRowGuidCol') 
= 1
```