# Can't find a column that should exist in a Northwind database table

Tags: sql, northwind

I just downloaded the Northwind db from microsoft and am following the instructions at w3schools. I'm in the Joins chapter and am looking for the CustomerName column in the Customers table, but can't find it... Am I losing my mind? Any help appreciated.

I have searched StackOverflow and Google to no avail.
I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the database, again, to no avail.

[Image from w3schools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IVSm.jpg)

[Image from my SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2kRW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like w3schools documentation has an error in it. The column you are looking for is `CompanyName`. You could also follow [AdaTheDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name) answer to search the db for columns by name.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%MyName%'
```

The diagram on [codeplex](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) shows CompanyName as well.

[Image http://i3.codeplex.com/download?ProjectName=northwinddatabase&DownloadId=269240](http://i3.codeplex.com/download?ProjectName=northwinddatabase&DownloadId=269240)

Comment: Yes, I noticed CompanyName is what CustomerName is (or vise versa...), but since I'm pretty new to SQL, I wanted to make certain I wasn't missing something. Also, thanks for the link for searching db columns by name!