# Search for field in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

What's the quickest way to find what table a field is in?  I just started at a new company and I'm not yet familiar with their DB's schema.  I frequently have a metric or dimension that I need to search for and it seems very time consuming as they have a very large DB.

I know this is a vague question and there is no best answer, but I'm looking for best practices, tips, and tricks that people have learned over the years which I might be able to leverage in this case.

Comment: `select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'your column name'`

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sys.columns` for that:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.name = <column_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the following query when I’m searching for a field.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'search_field%'
```

Make sure you have the DB you’re interested in selected.

Then, once you find the table you’re looking for you can create a DB diagram and ‘show related fields’ to see how to join that table on what you already have.

Comment: [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Comment: Hey Felix, this is a large article. In short, is there an issue with Jessica and prdp's answer?

Comment: @Victor If you're just searching for which tables a column is used, this is okay. But if you're going to need some additional information, `INFORATION_SCHEMA`does not provide them all.