# Find a table where the primary key is known

Tags: sql-server

I have a weird situation.  I have a case where I know a primary key column, but not the table it's in.

Anyone know a quick 'n easy way of finding that info?  i was hoping that sp_pkeys could do that, but it doesn't let me use the column as a parameter.

**Edit:** This is NOT the same as looking for tables with a *column* (I already know how to do that).  I'm looking for tables with a specific *primary key* (which is a *subset* of the "duplicate question").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all tables containing column with specified name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name)

Comment: No, not the same question.  I already know how to find tables with the specific column; I'm looking for a table with a specific primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumnName'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this.

```
select OBJECT_NAME(c.Object_ID)
from sys.columns c
join sys.indexes i on c.object_id = i.object_id 
where i.is_primary_key = 1
    and c.name = 'YourColumn'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me -- to test it out, I tried running sp_pkeys with the results, and it gave me answers where it gave me a PK with a different column.  Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you have tables with the same name in different schemas. Oh well...looks like you have an answer that works for you.

Comment: Maybe.  Since I know you from SSC, I'm biased, and wanted to mark yours as the answer, but c'est la vie. :-)  Oh well.

Comment: Nah. You should only be biased to get the best possible answer. Which in this case is not mine. Thanks for the thought though. :)