# How to check which table a column belongs to in SQL database

Tags: sql

I have about 600 database tables in my sql database. I  have a column that needs to be removed but I don't know how many tables it was defined or referenced in. Is there a way to check how many tables a column is referenced in?

Comment: Use the dictionary table `information_schema.columns`!

Comment: that should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? ("SQL" is only a query language, not the name of a database product - all relational databases are "SQL databases")