# How to find if all the columns in table A are present in table B or not

Tags: sql, database

```html
Table A
Id name phone
1 sam   7753457893
2 tom   7753457893
3 pop   7753457893
4 john  7753457893

table B

name phone
sam   7753457893
tom   7753457893
pop   7753457893
john  7753457893
```

How to find if all the columns in table A are present in table B or not. I tried using except but I am getting a compilation error "invalid no of columns for set operator input branches, expected 22, got 11 ".I used this query
"select * from table B 
except 
select * from table A".
Table A has 22 columns and table B has 11 columns. I need a query to know that all the columns in table B are in table A

Basically I want to know table B is a subset of table A or not.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: Mostly you have to query on the information schema of your database. You have to provide more details about database.(ORACLE/MySQL/MSSQLServer). Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query 
`SELECT ColumnFromB
FROM TableB
EXCEPT
SELECT ColumnFromA
FROM TableA`
This will give you a list of records that are in B but not in A.
Then you can insert the result into a table variable, and check its COUNT 
(if count= 0 'subset'
else is not subset).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to query for large no of columns lets say A have 100 columns and B have 70 columns.

Comment: You can use * rather than names of columns.