# How to select columns of a table whom column name end with '_old' in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert values into a table whoz table column name end with "_old"

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(1,2,3) WHERE column LIKE '%_old%' doesn't work

Comment: You would probably need to write a stored procedure to do this, because you would need to build the query dynamically.  Your current approach will not work.

Comment: i am doing this in a plpgsql function to later bind it to a trigger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all tables containing column with specified name - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name-ms-sql-server)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generic_trigger_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO person_audit VALUES(OLD.*) name LIKE '%_old%';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: @Pribina This question is tagged with Postgres, _not_ SQL Server.

Comment: Read about the information schema tables.  You will probably have to use them here.

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: `insert into table_name (col1_old, col2_old, col3_old) values (1,2,3);`

Comment: i have many columns like that  this approach wont work

Comment: We'll need more details.  How do you know how many values to insert per table?