# Kentico - Unable to find a custom user column

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I just took over a project from a developer who has already left an organisation and I'm doing some maintenance work in the project. I can see the following code in a custom web part

```
CurrentUserInfo CurrentUser = MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser;
DateTime ExpirationDate = CurrentUser.GetValue("aps_expirationdate", DateTime.Now);
```

The strange thing is, I cannot seem to find this custom field 'aps_expirationdate' anywhere in the system or in the database.

I checked the following places but couldn't find it.

- Checked Membership module 'User' class and 'User - Settings' class
- Checked 'User' module
- Did a manual Sql Search in the database to find a table with a column name 'aps_expirationdate'

but I cannot seem to find this column anywhere and the other strange thing is, when I debug the code it does return a date value. No bugs in the code so, cannot say that this is an invalid column name. Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've put in your initial question, it sounds as if the column was added manually and not through the Kentico UI.  In order for the data access layer or the Kentico API to know that field exists, the definition has to be stored within the Kentico module class and not just in the database.

Here's what I'd do to correct this:

1. Find what table the field exists in.  If you want the custom field to be part of the User or User Settings objects then they need to be added to either the `CMS_User` or `CMS_UserSetting` table.
2. If the field does not exist in either the `CMS_User` or `CMS_UserSetting` table, then go to the Modules app in the Kentico UI.
3. In the Modules App, go to Membership > Classes > Users > Fields and add the `aps_expirationdate` field.
4. If you have data in the field `aps_expirationdate` in the other table, write a query to copy it from the other table to the `CMS_User` table.
5. Now the API call as noted above will work.

If the field is already in the `CMS_User` or `CMS_UserSetting` table, then you will have to do the following:

1. In SSMS, rename that field to `aps_expirationdate_old`.
2. In the Modules App, go to Membership > Classes > Users > Fields and add the `aps_expirationdate` field.
3. Assuming you have data in the `aps_expirationdate_old` field in the `CMS_User` or `CMS_UserSetting` table, write a query to copy it from the other table to the `CMS_User` table.

Your last bullet point states you "*Did a manual Sql Search in the database to find a table with a column name 'aps_expirationdate'*".  This contradicts what you state at the end of your question which states "*I cannot seem to find this column anywhere*".  If you cannot find what table the `aps_expirationdate` exists in, then check out the following SO answer to find that column in a given database.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849704/698678