# How can I find occurrences of a column name FPPaymentID in the entire database (e.g table, stored procedure etc) in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

How can I find occurrences of a column name FPPaymentID in the entire database (e.g table, stored procedure etc) in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

I have to add a few more columns(4 new columns) in the same table and every section where FPPaymentID is used.
Please see pic for more info.[image]

I am looking for an Excel-like find feature.

Comment: Have you consulted the system objects? Specifically the `columns` and `tables` system objects?

Comment: Also, what is a "field" in this context? Tables don't have fields, and you use "column" (correctly) prior in the post implying that a "field" is something different.

Comment: I mean columns.

Comment: I am not an SQL person. Can someone please tell me how to use system objects?

Comment: What were wrong with the answers in [Find all tables containing column with specified name - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name-ms-sql-server)?

Comment: Find all tables containing column with specified name - MS SQL Server only gives me the column name in the tables, What about stored procedure, views etc