# How to get one value each from column which is in multiple tables (more than 1000) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know if this is even possible in an easier manner but I have a Database that has over 5000 tables spread across. I am looking to get one record each for a column named 'FirstName' which is across each of the table. That column name is NOT the same across each table i.e. just the name of the column is FirstName' but it can have any value in it.

Is there a way to do it other than using Union ALL?

Comment: Define "first". Relational database explicitly disclaim any responsibility for any kind of inherent record order, and can even reorder records on disk if needed.

Comment: Lets say I have FirstName, LastName, Age as columns in all these tables (each table has varied count) then all I want is the first entry in each of the table. If its any easier, then I dont mind getting 'one' record per table (not necessarily first) but the record has to be from 'FirstName' column.

Comment: this might give you a good start https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35529/how-to-select-the-first-10-records-for-each-table-in-the-same-database-using-sql  and then combine that with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name-ms-sql-server

Comment: Thank you! I have the exact query from the second stackoverflow answer which is giving me list of all 1000 tables as resultset. I need to now figure out how do I use that as Input to get what I want. Will check the first website and see it goes.