Search SQL Server Database by Keyword to Return the keyword, table, and dbo
I'm trying to recall an older query I used to easily locate column names in large databases on SQL server.
For example I'm looking for a keyword '%specialist%' to see how many tables it belongs to and what those tables are labeled as so I can write queries from those tables containing the keyword.
I scanned through similar questions but the answers didn't yield results.
Maybe I don't have access to all the tables? But I know I have enough access to bring that keyword back for 6-10 different tables or views.
Can any assist me?
This is what I thought might be right:
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'specialists%'

This is what I thought might be right: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'specialists%'
Results were blank
Tried an alternative:
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'specialist%'

Results were blank.

Do you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name

Try LIKE '%specialist%'

Use like when using '%%' not =
 select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   where COLUMN_NAME like '%specialist%' 


This does work and confirms my suspicions that since I'm only getting one result back that I must not have full access.
