# Update single column found in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the same column in multiple tables in my database.  I need to update every table that contains that column where the value is equal to 'xxxx'.  There's a very similar stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797142/i-have-the-same-column-in-multiple-tables-and-want-to-update-that-column-in-all) which is close to what I'm looking for - I just need to add another condition in my `WHERE` statement.  I'm not sure how to include it in the query as I keep getting syntax errors.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET customer= ''NewCustomerValue'' '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'customer'
```

The part I'm having problems with is how to include the below line in the 'WHERE' statement.

```
AND customer='xxxx'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' SET customer= ''NewCustomerValue'' where customer=''xxxx'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'customer'
```

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks for saving me from writing out a bunch of individual update statements :)

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff for the edit and correcting the answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
' AND customer=''xxxx''  ' --(two ' inside a string = ')
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explained or included a reference as to why this is required (what two single quotes achieves).

Comment: In T-SQL, When you want to include a single quote inside a string, you need to use TWO single quotes. The reason for that is to allow SQL Server to identify that this is not a piece of code but a string value.